# Change HTML using backstretch

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

Currently I display a slider on my website using Backstretch.
Above the slider I have a text block.
It is possible to change the (html) text every time the image changes?

```
<script>
                    jQuery(".header-slider-container").backstretch([
                      <?php
                           foreach ($background_slider as $slide) :
                           $image = $slide['afbeelding'];
                           $text_slider = $slide['tekst_slider'];

                      ?>

                            "<?= $image['url'] ?>",
                     <?php
                           endforeach;
                     ?>

                        ], {
                        duration: 4000,
                        transition: 'fade',
                        transitionDuration: 600

                    });
```

I have already created an extra field in wordpress and can retrieve the value ($text_slider = $slide['tekst_slider'];) , but how do I change this?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used that plugin before, but by reading their [documentation](https://github.com/jquery-backstretch/jquery-backstretch), it looks like you can listen to an event that is triggered either *before* or *after* a new image shows. This is a sample code from their doc that is triggered after an image loads:

```
$(window).on("backstretch.after", function (e, instance, index) {
  // Do something
});
```

Where it says `Do something` is where you would place your code to change the HTML as needed.